# estimatedRowHeight API breaks custom cell sometimes

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8

I am using the new iOS 8 API:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This works well in most situations, but it breaks my custom cell if the height of the cell is calculated dynamically sometimes:

[image]

Some more information:

1. It seems tableview does calculate the height correctly(it has empty space between 2 cells), but somehow part of the cell is hidden.
2. the shown part (the part with white background) of the cell is as height as the cell in my xib file is.
3. it only happens when the calculated height of the cell is bigger than the hight I set in xib file(which is 60 in my case). If the height is equal to the cell height in xib, it works well. I **didn't** set any constraint on the height in my xib though.

Comment: I look like you have a view inside the cell and the view is not being resized. Would be nice to see how the cell is created.

Comment: The view is a cell whose number of lines is 0. Did you mean you want to see my xib by `Would be nice to see how the cell is created`? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you created custom cells via xib files and Interface Builder, correct?

There are settings to use custom heights and set the custom heights in both the cell and table view details in IB. For the cell, I think it's the height property and you check the custom box and input your height.

For the table view, there's a row height property that you check custom for and choose your height there.

I've had wonky stuff happen to my custom cells without making sure these settings are appropriate in IB.

Let me know if that works or if there is another problem!